# Working Difference between th:action and th:formaction in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am new to Thymeleaf.I am having a Spring-Boot app which used Thymeleaf component in view pages.

Now while using eclipse code assist I came across few thymeleaf tag/attributes namely `th:form,th:formaction`.

Once I change my above code to following format :

**Its stopped working.My webpage is not getting submitted to server**.
So,I wanted to understand the following things:

***What is the use of th:form tag?
What is the difference between th:action and th:formaction tag?***

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ´th:action´ and ´th:formaction´ tags will create the html tags `action` and `formaction`. This question is not really related to Thymeleaf but the html tags itself.

The `action` tag can be placed onto a form to specify the url to pass the form to. In your first example submitting the form will send a POST request to `/saveStudent`.

The second example is not valid HTML that's why the form will not submit. `formaction` can be used to override the `action` attribute of the form within the form. It can be used on `input` tags:

```
<form th:action="@{/saveStudent}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
  <table>
    <tr> 
      <td>Enter Your name</td>
      <td><input type="text"  th:field="*{userName}"/></td>
      <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
      <td><input th:formaction="@{/saveSomewhereElse}" type="submit" value="Submit to other url"/></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

In this example the default `action` is to submit to `/saveStudent` but if someone clicks the second submit button the form will submit to `/saveSomewhereElse`.

In general you probably will need just the `action` tag in 99% of the cases.